# Can I declare a NSMutableArray as a property in a Shared Object

Tags: objective-c, singleton, nsmutablearray, instance, shared

I/m developing for iOS 7 and using arc. I'm trying to create a shred instance that contains an NSMutableArray and having some trouble. 
in my header file I have the following

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SharedDataController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *qrcodes;

+(id) sharedInstance;

@end
```

and in my implimentation

```
@synthesize text1,text2,text3, qrcodes;

+(id) sharedInstance
{
    static id sharedInstance = nil;
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        NSLog(@"creating shared instance contoller");
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

when I try to add an object to the array

```
SharedDataController *sharedDataController = [SharedDataController sharedInstance];

[sharedDataController.qrcodes addObject:result.text];
NSLog(@"%@", sharedDataController.qrcodes);
```

I get nil, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Search for "Objective-C singleton" and change the code for creating the singleton according to what you find. Your code is not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy to use Try this :

```
sharedDataController.qrcodes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:result.text, nil];
```

It will work for you . Its returning nil because of singleton class and in singleton class changes always be static .

Note: You can also assign whole array in same way.